# Disable ASP.NET server error pages in production environment

Tags: asp.net, iis, error-handling

I would like the following behavior in regards to error statuscode responses:

- In JsonResult Actions (for AJAX postbacks), return custom body along with some error statuscode
- For errors in other action methods, show IIS (custom) error page
- For 404 errors, show IIS (custom) error page
- In local environment: For errors in non-json action methods, and 404, show ASP.NET error page with stacktrace

If I set `existingResponse=Replace` in the `httpErrors` element in web.config, the IIS error pages override any response with an error-statuscode. That is I cannot return a custom json response.
If I set `existingResponse=Auto` I can return a custom json response by setting `Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors=true`, but then the ASP.NET (custom) error pages are shown for any other error statuscode. That is, it never falls back to the IIS error pages. It seems that ASP.NET automatically sets the `TrySkipIisCustomErrors` on server errors, which I do not want.

Is there any way to achieve what I describe? I could possibly use the ASP.NET `customErrors` section instead, but I realize it also has disadvantages, as described here:
https://dusted.codes/demystifying-aspnet-mvc-5-error-pages-and-error-logging

One could use a combination of `httpErrors`and `customErrors`, but the latter does no support `ExecuteURL` - only static error pages. That is unfortunate since I would like to make use of the master `Layout.cshtml`.

Any suggestions?